# Simple web App development in Ruby/Sinatra -imputed "submitted info" is not being fetched

Tags: ruby, web-applications, sinatra, mechanize

My goal is to create a simple web app, in which the visitor can input their favorite artist to see what is currently available at an auction along with the estimated price. Let's use the artist  `Robert Genn` as an example

When I run the code in ruby, I get through on the `http://localhost:4567/` page and from what I see; it is a simple shell of what I ultimately want to create. However once I input my artist of interest ie `Robert Genn` I get an error page.

Here are my two code files .rb first and .erb following that

---

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'mechanize'

get '/' do
    @greeting = "WELCOME! WHAT ARTIST WOULD YOU LIKE TO LOOK UP TODAY?"
    erb :index
end

agent = Mechanize.new

page = agent.get('http://www.invaluable.com/')

search_form = page.form
search_terms = gets.chomp.delete(",")

search_form['withAll'] = search_terms

page = search_form.submit

items = page.css('.lot')
item = page.css('.estimate normal')

items.each do |item|
    return "#{item.css('span').text} #{items.css('span').text}"

end
```

---

Here is my .erb file

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">

            <h1><%= @greeting %></h1>
            <p>What artist are you seeking today?</p>
            <form action="/" method="POST" class="form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="ticker" class="form-control">
                </div>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are many things wrong with your sample.

You need to put all of your code in your `get '/' do` block or better in a helper file/module.

The use of something like mechanize to query an external source is a bad decision. While it is ok to query external sources, do it with a [Net::HTTP](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) GET or something like that. Mechanize is going to start a browser on the server and this is doomed to fail.

The use of gets is also not done on a server or with the results of a form.

I suggest you do some reading on Sinatra first, many good examples (eg at [http://www.sinatrarb.com](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)/) and some books to choose from.
eg:
https://www.geekbooks.me/book/view/jump-start-sinatra
http://dl.finebook.ir/book/26/14702.pdf

Also try to chop your code into pieces you can test by themselves, eg the querying of the external source can be extracted in a method that you can first test before implement it in the rest of your code.

In this case I suppose there will be many errors because of the above but in the future give us a stacktrace of the error you get so that we can better help you.

Can't give you code becuase I would have to rewrite everything which is not our purpose. Don't give up and keep learning and Success !